# Apache kills my Mac. It didn't up until now. What happened?

Tags: macos, performance, apache-http-server, mysql

Running Web Sharing on Mac (localhost Apache + MySQL settings) kills my Mac. It opens 30-40 httpd sequences, takes up to 90% percent CPU power, and keeps the fan running constantly.

`sudo apachectl stop` keeps the CPU safe, but then again -- I need the Apache running :)

What can I do the solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: More info, please.... (System details, apache and mysql version, maybe even your httpd.conf file, etc...)

Comment: This is my problem: http://jestro.com/optimize-apache-slow-vps-wordpress/ -- Though the fix won't work (localhost is not functioning when commenting out these modules)

Comment: MacBook (intel) + Snow Leopard, 4GB RAM, 43GB free space. httpd.conf coming up.

Answer (score 1):

Found the source of the problem: .htaccess mod_rewrite on crashes Wordpress when textual permalinks are set.

This is weird, but at least it's not system.

Comment: WordPress is full of bugs; it would only be "weird" if it worked properly.